# Hooking WeChat using Xposed for incoming messages

Tags: message, wechat, xposed

I want to use Xposed to hook the method in WeChat that is responsible for incoming messages. Which method should I hook？ Which procedure should I follow to find this method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to xposed. Start by hooking methods for open source apps. You'll get familiar with android apps code and design. Once you have an idea about xposed code you can start decompiling the apks.
for decompiling you can use apktool. apktool generates a smali code. 
I prefer decompiling using online decompilers as it generates java code.

but beware the smali code is accurate while the generated java code is not.

for xposed you can see existing open source xposed modules. That will help you to get familiar with xposed APIs as there are no examples provided by xposed author himself ( correct me if I'm wrong here ).

you can refer my xposed module code here
https://github.com/suraj0208/WhatsappExtensions